# REPL Init file on Windows

Tags: idris

Where can I put my init script for the `idris` REPL in Windows?

If I put the commands in

```
C:\Users\frankr85\Application Data\idris\repl\init
```

the content is not loaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It is - at least for me - here:

```
C:\Users\frankr85\AppData\Roaming\idris\repl
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory is `%appdata%/idris/repl/` and the init file is `init`.
i.e. `%appdata%/idris/repl/init`